# Using PowerShell to modify MS Word cell borders

Tags: powershell

I routinely create reports using MS Word. Part of this report contains a table, which I have been copying manually from Excel into the word document. I am trying to use PowerShell in order to do this automatically, but I am having trouble finding the correct formatting commands. Specifically, I am currently trying to format the table so that every border between rows is dotted instead of solid, but the borders between columns are invisible. So something like this:

Heading1   Heading2   Heading3
.................................................
H1Item1    H2Item1    H3Item1
.................................................
H1Item2    H2Item2    H3Item2
.................................................

I did find that this gets me going in the right direction, but doesn't quite provide the granularity of border control that I'm looking for:

```
$Table.Range.Style = "Table Grid"
$Table.Borders.InsideLineStyle = 2
$Table.Borders.OutsideLineStyle = 0
```

If there is any good documentation on formatting Word paramters through PowerShell, I would really appreciate the pointer. I've managed to find articles relating to how to do specific things, but no good documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha! I found it. I was trying for a way to do it in one line, but I found that if I just edit each row as I'm adding the data to it, then I can get the whole table that way. This is the line I added to my Foreach loop:

```
$Table.Rows($x).Borders.InsideLineStyle = 0
```

I would still love a link to some good documentation if anyone knows of any!